# Why mongoose.model() is required to get data from MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to read data from the `mongodb` with `mongoose`, but every time it requires creating a `model`. Why?
I thought `model` are just like templates to insert data to MongoDB.
Can anyone describe what exactly `mongoose.model()` is and how it works?

I tried

```
const Model = mongoose.model(mongoose.Schima())
```

Without object in it
And it worked as well!!!

How does `mongoose.model` get data in background?

Thank you...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose models are much more than just templates on how to store data in the database: they perform type conversion, provide validation, have pre/post hooks, provide easy methods for population, and much more.

You don't *need* to use a full model to retrieve data from the database (in fact, you don't even need Mongoose at all), but you'll lose all the additional features.